# SKLearn DT regressor - good enough score?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, decision-trees, score

What constitutes as a "good enough" score for a Decision Tree Regressor? The `.score()` function gives us a general score about our model. This can be 1 if the model predicts all data with a 100% accuracy, and can be arbitrarily worse. If I understand correctly, a score of 0 means the prediction is quasi constant. But starting with what value can we say that the prediction is "usable" (i know this is ambiguous, but still). Is a score of 0.4-0.5 good enough to use the predictions in practice as opposed to not using any machine learning techniques?

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the score depends on the context of the project.

One approach is a model comparison approach. Define a baseline model. Then see if Decision Tree Regressor is better than the baseline.